# Passing variables to another classes (Java)

Tags: java, variables

I have a Java program that contains multiple classes, all of which extend JPanel (except for the class containing the main method). I am trying to pass int variables from one class to another and, using some previously asked questions, came up with this:

Class RollPanel

```
    public int getbrainCount()
    {
    return brainCount;
    }
```

Class BrainsPanel (where I am trying to send the variable)

```
   void setbrainCount()
   {
   RollPanel rollpanel = new RollPanel();
   brainCount = rollpanel.getbrainCount();
   }
```

This doesn't give any errors, but when I add brainCount to a label to see its value, it is always 0.

brainCount is declared at the class level of RollPanel, then given a value with this code which is in a button listener:

```
        value1 = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;
        value2 = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;
        value3 = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;
        //rollTotal++;

        //Counts how many brains were rolled.
        if (value1 == 1)
            brainCount++;
        if (value2 == 1)
            brainCount++;
        if (value3 == 1)
            brainCount++;
```

I understand that just declaring a variable will automatically mean its value will be zero at first(which I assume is why it is displayed as zero), but how can I pass its *updated* value after the above code to brainsPanel so I can add its value to a label in brainsPanel? Would getBrainCount() come after the button listener? I feel like I'm overlooking something simple here...

EDIT:
I think the problem isn't with the setter as it is the getter. Since in RollPanel(where the getter is) I declare brainCount as an int its initial value is 0, so when the getter gets the value it always remains at 0 even though brainCount should be altered in the button listener. Here is RollPanel in its entirety. How can I make the getter get the updated value of brainCount instead of its initial 0?

```
package zombiedice;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RollPanel extends JPanel
{
JLabel die1Label, die2Label, die3Label, testLabel;
JButton rollButton, sortButton;
JPanel dicePanel, buttonPanel;
ImageIcon die1, die2, die3;
int rollTotal, value1, value2, value3;
int brainCount, blastCount;
Random generator = new Random();



public RollPanel()
{
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 
    setBackground(Color.black);

    dicePanel = new JPanel();
    dicePanel.setBackground(Color.black);

    //Creates blank ImageIcons to be used later to display dice.
    die1 = new ImageIcon(); 
    die2 = new ImageIcon(); 
    die3 = new ImageIcon(); 

    //A panel just to hold the buttons.
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();

    //Creates and links roll button to RollListener.
    rollButton = new JButton("Roll");
    rollButton.addActionListener(new RollListener());
    buttonPanel.add(rollButton);

    //After a roll, this button will need to be clicked so brain and blast
    //die can be sorted into their proper catergories. 
    sortButton = new JButton("Sort");
    sortButton.addActionListener(new SortListener());


    //Creates labels out of the dice images.
    die1Label = new JLabel(die1);
    die2Label = new JLabel(die2);
    die3Label = new JLabel(die3);

    //Adds image labels to the panel that holds the dice.
    dicePanel.add(die1Label);
    dicePanel.add(die2Label);
    dicePanel.add(die3Label);

    add(dicePanel);
    add(buttonPanel);
} //Closes constructor



//Roll button listener.
private class RollListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        rollButton.setEnabled(false);
        repaint();
        buttonPanel.add(sortButton);
        repaint(); 
        sortButton.setEnabled(true);
        repaint();

        value1 = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;
        value2 = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;
        value3 = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;
        //rollTotal++;

        //Counts how many brains were rolled.
        if (value1 == 1)
            brainCount++;
        if (value2 == 1)
            brainCount++;
        if (value3 == 1)
            brainCount++;

        //Updates the dice
        die1Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(value1 + ".png"));
        die2Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(value2 + ".png"));
        die3Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(value3 + ".png")); 



    } //Closes actionPerformed
} //Closes the listener for the roll button



//Sort button listener.
private class SortListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        sortButton.setEnabled(false);
        repaint();
        rollButton.setEnabled(true);
        repaint();



    } //Closes actionPerformed.

}//Closes sort button listener. 
public int getBrainCount()
{
return brainCount;
} 

} //Closes class
```

BrainsPanel

```
package zombiedice;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BrainsPanel extends JPanel
{
ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon();
ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon();
JLabel brainTotal, label1, label2;
JPanel brainPanel;
int brainCount;


void setbrainCount(int count)
{
   // RollPanel rollpanel = new RollPanel();
   brainCount = count;
   //brainCount = count;
}

public BrainsPanel()
{


setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 

setBackground(Color.black);


icon1 = new ImageIcon("1.png");
icon2 = new ImageIcon("1.png");
label1 = new JLabel(icon1);
label2 = new JLabel(icon2);
brainTotal = new JLabel ("Brains eaten: " + brainCount);

add(label1);
add(label2);
add(brainTotal);



} //Closes constructor
} //Closes class
```

Comment: It's not clear what your `setbrainCount` method is *meant* to do. Usually a "setter" takes the new value, so it would be: `public void setBrainCount(int count) { brainCount = count; }`

Comment: It's also unclear what you're seeing, and how the bits of code interact with each other. A short but complete program would make it easier to tell what's going on - and ideally, without a GUI unless that's *really* necessary. (Console apps are much simpler to follow - and diagnose.)

Comment: It's meant to take the value of brainCount in RollPanel class set that value to a variable (in this case a variable also called brainCount) in BrainsPanel class so it can be added to a label in the BrainsPanel, just as you explained.  However, now I think the error is not with the setter as it is the getter (edited the original post)

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't follow that at all - but it's certainly odd that it's creating a *new* RollPanel instance...

Comment: You're right, the code you posted should be the setter method, and not new RollPanel. I've got it changed now.

Answer (score 0):

In this peace of code:

```
void setbrainCount() {
    RollPanel rollpanel = new RollPanel();
    brainCount = rollpanel.getbrainCount();
}
```

You always create a new `RollPanel` object before getting `brainCount`. Of course it is 0 if it is declared as field in `RollPanel`. The variable was newly initialized with the object creation just the line before.

You should make sure you always use the same `RollPanel` object, e.g. keep it as field in `BrainsPanel`. It's hard to say for sure with the given code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try the following:

```
void setbrainCount(RollPanel rollPanel)
{
    brainCount = rollpanel.getbrainCount();
}
```

This way you won't try to use the newly initialized value which is always 0.

Althozuh technically, it would make more sense to just send the count over and set that

```
void setbrainCount(int brainCount)
{
    this.brainCount = brainCount;
}
```